# Arduino NANO heating issue

Tags: arduino, uart, heat, rs232, hmi

I am trying use a HMI display with arduino NANO. I am powering arduino and hmi display ( [topway 5 inch smart display](https://www.topwaydisplay.com/en/product/smart-lcd/smart-lcd-module-HMT050DTA-D) ) with 9 volt adaptor. everyting works fine. but if I plugin the Tx, Rx pins which are coming from rs232 ttl converter ([this device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000322274971.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4a1d4c4dWcxHJU)) to arduino nano's Rx and Tx pins, arduino nano is starting heating. I have waited one day heating was not to much but there was a heating issue. Also there is no problem communication between arduino nano and hmi display. If I plug out the rx and tx pins, there was no heating even after one day waiting. everythings looks fine. I guess that heating will make a problem in future within long term usage.

also if I powering rs232 converter with 5 volt, this time rs232 converter heating too much and broken. Therefore, I am powering rs232 converter with 3.3 volt. if I powering 3.3 volt there is no heating on rs232 converter.

this is my circuit diagram, sorry about my paint skill.

[image]

well, I didnt understand why arduino nano heating and how to fix that. Can you help me

Comment: Are you sure the TTL and RS232 side were connected correctly? And if that is a 3.3V MCU, then obviously the TTL-RS232 converter **must** be used with 3.3V supply. Regarding the wiring diagram, the black wire of the display goes via the TTL-RS232 converter, that may not be a good idea.

Comment: @Justme connection is right, you can check from rs232 product page (link above) and also I have tried and there is no problem data send and receive. the black wire, actually ı made pcb all grounds are poligoned. so all gnd is same. I dont think so it make heating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nano uses a 5V MCU (ATMega328). If you are going to connect it directly with the SP3232 then it should operate from the same supply or have a voltage translator between.

The SP3232, if it is genuine (doubt) should withstand up to 5.5V. That's not a lot of margin between that and 5V and you have routed the 500mA max current from the display *through* the RS-232 adapter board, which is **bad**. Run the ground wire from the display back to the supply directly. You don't need another ground wire to the adapter, there is enough noise margin in the RS-232. I have seen similar genuine chips fail from minor disturbances in the supply, they are not as robust as the old 5V-only MAX232 chips.

Comment: well I will try to make a simple 20k/10k voltage diveder, I will informd you. Also you are totally right The SP3232 is bad***. but I didnt find any rs232 converter like that pcb on internet. generally all rs converter has db9 header like that https://nettigo.eu/products/max3232-rs232-ttl-converter